# In Vim, how can I delete all text from the current cursor position until the next space?

Tags: vim

In Vim, I know `d$`, that deletes everything to the end of line.

But how can I delete all text from the current cursor position until the next space? `dw` doesn't work, since it treats symbols like colon as separator as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607904/vim-deleting-from-current-position-until-a-space

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`dW` (capital `W`) or more generally you can do `df` followed by the character to search for, in this case space.  You can also use `t` instead of `f` to delete up to but not including the found character.  And if you capitalize the `F` or `T`, they work backwards.

Comment: +1 for `dt`, d t space worked for me

Comment: `dE` deletes to the end of the WORD

Answer (score 3):

You can also delete until a search string, thus `d/<Space>` will delete until, but not including, the first space from the cursor position.

Comment: Anybody an idea on how to escape a space in the code-tics?

Comment: Just use the same convention as the Vim help file: `d/<Space>`.

Answer (score 2):

The best (fewest keystrokes) way is

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>

This deletes all text from the current position until the next space. From the help ([`:h E`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#E))

```
                                                        E
E                       Forward to the end of WORD [count] inclusive.
                        Does not stop in an empty line.
...
                                                        WORD
A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.
```

Comment: ... and what does this do?

Comment: It does exactly and precisely what the O.P. requested.

Comment: Holy smokes! It does? I can't believe it!

Comment: Oh.  I suddenly understand the sarcasm...I didn't realize how old this question was when I posted.  Sorry, I'm new here....  :(

Comment: Posting to an old question is not a problem. But posting a command without any explanation is.

Comment: Got it, good to know.